# Global_planner package with A* planner question

Tags: navigation, base-global-planner, global-planner, move-base, baseglobalplanner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to this [post](http://answers.ros.org/question/64922/navfn-potential-field-calculation/) the [global_planner package](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/hydro-devel/global_planner) is a refactoring of the NavFn package.

The [global_planner package](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/hydro-devel/global_planner) also has an A* planner implemented and seems to be much cleaner than the NavFn package.

- What is the status of the global_planner package?
- Is it going to eventually replace the navfn package as the default global_planner?
- Is the global_planner package a drop in replacement for the navfn package?
- If not, how should the global_planner package be setup?

I noticed that the global_planner package does not get pulled down with the navigation stack and needs to be pulled separately with "sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-global-planner". For using with move_base the package does not have the pluginlib xml file that goes with it and it does not export the library as a nav_core plugin in its package.xml.  Is there a reason for this?  Is this something that is going to be added?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98511/global_planner-package-with-a*-planner-question./) by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2013-11-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Status of Global_planner** - I'm not sure if the latest version is in the debs yet, but the global_planner is stable and supported.

**Replacement** - I intended it as a replacement, but did not delete navfn for backwards compatibility. It should be a drop-in replacement.

The exclusion of the pluginlib xml is an oversight and shall be updated soon. I will also try to make a wiki page.

**Important Note** - Although you think it would, A* does NOT provide the same path as using Dijikstra's, which I discovered only recently. The potential field calculations that Navfn performs require a wide swath of values in the grid, and thus A* does not provide enough values to get a similarly smooth path. I'll try to include an illustration of this on the wiki.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) on 2013-11-06**:
Thank you for the update.  Do you know when the latest might be apart of the debs build?  Would you be able to update this page when a wiki page is created?  I am going to see if I can get it working probably sometime next week.  I will let you know if I have any questions.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-12-16**:
Hey Raptor. I finally updated the wiki page. Enjoy: http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-12-16**:
(Although not all versions have the fixes yet...notably the old_navfn_behavior is the default and the parameter is not implemented)

**Comment by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) on 2013-12-17**:
Awesome!  I will check it out.  Thank you.

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2014-01-21**:
@David Lu I am trying to use the global_planner, I added it in move_base parameters as base_global_planner: global_planner/PlannerCore but it keeps saying this planner is not registered. I've used it from debs and git repo. Is there an example of a launch file with yamls? Thanks!

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-01-21**:
Marti - Can you please post this as its own question?

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2014-01-21**:
Yes, sorry :)

**Comment by [mateus03](https://answers.ros.org/users/18781/mateus03/) on 2014-10-08**:
@David Lu I've found out why A* gives a different path from Dijkstra. The issue is that you use the Manhattan distance has heuristic, if you use the Euclidean distance the paths will be almost identical.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-10-08**:
@mateus03 - That's an excellent point. https://github.com/DLu/navigation/tree/global_planner_heuristic